# Dealing with the surprising lack of ParList in scala.collections.parallel

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, parallel-processing, scala-collections

So scala 2.9 recently turned up in Debian testing, bringing the newfangled parallel collections with it.

Suppose I have some code equivalent to

```
  def expensiveFunction(x:Int):Int = {...}

  def process(s:List[Int]):List[Int} = s.map(expensiveFunction)
```

now from the teeny bit I'd gleaned about parallel collections before the docs actually turned up on my machine, I was expecting to parallelize this just by switching the List to a `ParList`... but to my surprise, there isn't one!  (Just `ParVector`, `ParMap`, `ParSet`...).

As a workround, this (or a one-line equivalent) seems to work well enough:

```
  def process(s:List[Int]):List[Int} = {
    val ps=scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector()++s
    val pr=ps.map(expensiveFunction)
    List()++pr
  }
```

yielding an approximately x3 performance improvement in my test code and achieving massively higher CPU usage (quad core plus hyperthreading i7).  But it seems kind of clunky.

My question is a sort of an aggregated:

- Why isn't there a `ParList` ?
- Given there isn't a `ParList`, is there a
  better pattern/idiom I should adopt so that
  I don't feel like they're missing ?
- Am I just "behind the times" using Lists a
  lot in my scala programs (like all the Scala books I
  bought back in the 2.7 days taught me) and
  I should actually be making more use of
  `Vectors` ?  (I mean in C++ land
  I'd generally need a pretty good reason to use
  `std::list` over `std::vector`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let me show you how to make a parallel version of that code:

```
def expensiveFunction(x:Int):Int = {...}

def process(s:List[Int]):Seq[Int] = s.par.map(expensiveFunction).seq
```

That will have Scala figure things out for you -- and, by the way, it uses ParVector. If you really want `List`, call `.toList` instead of `.seq`.

As for the questions:

- There isn't a `ParList` because a `List` is an intrinsically non-parallel data structure, because any operation on it requires traversal.
- You should code to traits instead of classes -- `Seq`, `ParSeq` and `GenSeq`, for example. Even performance characteristics of a `List` are guaranteed by `LinearSeq`.
- All the books before Scala 2.8 did not have the new collections library in mind. In particular, the collections really didn't share a consistent and complete API. Now they do, and you'll gain much by taking advantage of it.

  Furthermore, there wasn't a collection like `Vector` in Scala 2.7 -- an immutable collection with (near) constant indexed access.

Answer (score 15):

`List`s are great when you want pattern matching (i.e. `case x :: xs`) and for efficient prepending/iteration. However, they are not so great when you want fast access-by-index, or splitting into chunks, or joining (i.e. `xs ::: ys`).

Hence it does not make much sense (to have a parallel `List`) when you think that this kind of thing (splitting and joining) is *exactly* what is needed for efficient parallelism. Use:

```
xs.toIndexedSeq.par
```

Answer (score 7):

A `List` cannot be easily split into various sub-lists which makes it hard to parallelise. For one, it has O(n) access; also a `List` cannot strip its tail, so one need to include a length parameter.

I guess, taking a `Vector` will be the better solution.

Note that Scala’s `Vector` is different from `std::vector`. The latter is basically a wrapper around standard array, a contiguous block in memory which needs to be copied every now and then when adding or removing data. Scala’s `Vector` is a specialised data structure which allows for efficient copying and splitting while keeping the data itself immutable.