# Different result returned using Scala Collection par in a series of runs

Tags: scala

I have tasks that I want to execute concurrently and each task takes substantial amount of memory so I have to execute them in batches of 2 to conserve memory.

```
def runme(n: Int = 120) = (1 to n).grouped(2).toList.flatMap{tuple =>
    tuple.par.map{x => {
        println(s"Running $x")
        val s = (1 to 100000).toList // intentionally to make the JVM allocate a sizeable chunk of memory
        s.sum.toLong
    }}
}

val result = runme()
println(result.size + " => " + result.sum)
```

The result I expected from the output was `120 => 84609924480` but the output was rather random. The returned collection size differed from execution to execution. Most of the time there was missing count even though all the futures were executed looking at the console. I thought `flatMap` waits the parallel executions in `map` to complete before returning the complete. What should I do to always get the right result using `par`? Thanks

Comment: strange, I get the expected output every time. With parallel collections you should only care about mutable state (not your case) and not-associative operations  (here you are just transforming the list elements).

Comment: Seems to be related to turning `(1 to n).grouped(2)` into `List`. If you use something else (e.g. `toVector` or `toArray`), do you get the right result? Also, what logic do you use to say that the expected result is `120 => 84609924480`? I think that the expected result would be `120 => 600006000000`. Maybe you should do `s.map(_.toLong).sum` in order to not overflow.

Comment: mmm, there's no `ParList`. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642210/dealing-with-the-surprising-lack-of-parlist-in-scala-collections-parallel

Comment: I am pretty sure my expected result is correct i.e. `scala> 120 * (1 to 100000).sum.toLong` :)

@jarandaf I don't know if this makes any difference to the result, I am using Scala 2.11.5 with JDK 1.7 on OSX 10.10

Comment: I think the problem is your integer sum is overflowing. Where and when in the process it overflows differs from run to run (depending on when the parallel operations happen), and hence the result varies. Please try re-running it with longs everywhere, and see if this time it is consistent.

Comment: I encountered that earlier and I solved the overflow by converted the sum of list to Long. This was not the issue. The issue was solved with using the right type of collections.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: changing the underlying collection in this case shouldn't change the output of your program. The problem is related to this known [bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9126). It's fixed from 2.11.6, so if you use that (or higher) Scala version, you should not  see the strange behavior.

And about the overflow, I still think that your expected value is wrong. You can check that the sum is overflowing because the list is of integers (which are 32 bit) while the total sum exceeds the integer limits. You can check it with the following snippet:

```
val n = 100000

val s = (1 to n).toList // your original code
val yourValue = s.sum.toLong // your original code

val correctValue = 1l * n * (n + 1) / 2 // use math formula

var bruteForceValue = 0l // in case you don't trust math :) It's Long because of 0l
for (i ← 1 to n) bruteForceValue += i // iterate through range

println(s"yourValue       = $yourValue")
println(s"correctvalue    = $correctValue")
println(s"bruteForceValue = $bruteForceValue")
```

which produces the output

```
yourValue       = 705082704
correctvalue    = 5000050000
bruteForceValue = 5000050000
```

Cheers!

Comment: yes, you are right. i overlooked the overflowed of the sum of 1 to 100000. I was focused on the parallel collections and the number of elements returned rather than the sum. my bad. thanks for highlighting this again to me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kaktusito.

It worked after I changed the grouped list to Vector or Seq i.e. `(1 to n).grouped(2).toList.flatMap{...` to `(1 to n).grouped(2).toVector.flatMap{...`

Comment: I still don't understand why your initial solution does not work (for me it does). You parallelize `tuple`, which is actually a `Vector`. To me, using `toList` or `toVector` makes no difference (you flatmap over it, and parallelize the contents, which are vectors). I would agree more on @Paul's suggestion thinking about possible overflows.

Comment: @jarandaf It should work, you are right about that. It's a known bug. See my answer.